# Cant trigger stake functionality in my staking smart contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I am using this smart contract [solidity by example](https://solidity-by-example.org/defi/staking-rewards/) only difference i added approve function so that i can approve amount to spend from my staking smart contract using interface

```
function approve(uint _amount) external{
    stakingToken.approve(address(this), _amount);
}
```

after deployment i:

trigger setRewardsDuration
send my rewards token to my staking smart contract with metamask,
after that i trigger notifyRewardAmount,
then hit approve and set _amount to some amount but made sure that i have enough in my metamask balance,
and then i try to stake with my stake function and pass same amount as i approved but then i get this generic error

```
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = execution reverted: invalid request","id":2994399924919834}
```

I am using Remix ide so this is what get as error dont have more details

i know that Smart Contract Programmer has nice video that go through this exactly example of smart contract but he does it locally and hit approve directly from erc20 smart contract, i cant do that because i dont have source code of erc20 tokens that i try to stake, so that why i just added my own function for approve.